# Fitting of Poisson log-linear model

Tags: r, model-fitting

I have considered 2 by 2 table and the data is about taking the pulse rate of students before and after running. I considered Ran (Yes/No) against PulseBefore and PulseAfter and made a contingency table. I fitted a poisson log linear model and got the output like this.

```
inde<-glm(dat$Ran1~dat$Pulse1+dat$Pulse2,family=poisson)
inde

Call:  glm(formula = dat$Ran1 ~ dat$Pulse1 + dat$Pulse2, family = poisson)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   dat$Pulse1   dat$Pulse2  
   -2.09795     -0.02745      0.02968  

Degrees of Freedom: 108 Total (i.e. Null);  106 Residual
Null Deviance:      79.37 
Residual Deviance: 37.21        AIC: 135.2
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe predict pulse rate 2 as a function of pulse rate 1 plus the interaction of rate 1 with whether or not they ran - e.g. (`glm(Pulse2 ~ Pulse1+ Pulse1:Ran1, data=at, family = poisson)`)

Comment: @  Marc in the box  If I consider this model then how will my contingency table look like? How can I identify the row and column effect model?

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks to me like it would make more sense to try to predict change in pulse rate from whether or not they ran.
2. If you really *did* want to treat Ran as the response variable, it's 0/1 so a Poisson count would not be the obvious choice -- a binomial model (logistic regression) makes more sense.